# Using Snackbar for 5.0+ devices

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-snackbar, snackbar

So I want to create an app supporting Lollipop & above devices **ONLY**.

But I have a use case that demands the need for a `Snackbar` with an UNDO option. After reading up, it seems I have to :

- Use a `CoordinatorLayout` (support library one)
- Use `AppCompatActivity`, not `Activity`
- Use `Theme.AppCompat.(...)` instead of `android:Theme.Material`
- Changes to every other view in the app including `ActionBar` just to be compatible with `AppCompat` (kinda ironic)

Is this really the only way to use a basic functionality like `Snackbar` - having to rewrite everything elsewhere?

Please please tell me there is a better way out. This just does not make any sense!

Comment: Have you tried it? Doesn't CoordinatorLayout work with plain Activity?

Comment: Tried, but it just crashes. Seems all these things need to be done! 

`12-27 18:51:33.441 2199-2199/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.perfectday, PID: 2199 
12-27 18:51:33.441 2199-2199/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.perfectday/com.example.perfectday.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: I tried it out, they key part of the stacktrace is here: 
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
                                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
                                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)`. So yes, you need to use appcompat for using the design library.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. This sucks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this really the only way to use a basic functionality like Snackbar - having to rewrite everything elsewhere?

Whether or not you need a `CoordinatorLayout` depends on where and how you are showing the `Snackbar`.

Beyond that, though, to use the official `Snackbar` implementation without modification, you have to go through all those shenanigans.

You are welcome to use [independent implementations of the snackbar pattern](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=snackbar), such as [this one that I use](https://github.com/MrEngineer13/SnackBar). AFAIK they have all been discontinued by their authors, in favor of the official implementation.

Comment: @magicmushroom: "So when I use AppCompat, what all things need to be changed?" -- mostly your second and third bullets, plus your menu resources will need some attributes moved into a custom namespace (e.g., `app:showAsAction`). "Do I need to also change each TextView/ Button to be a "android.support" one?" -- no, any such conversions there are applied automatically when you use `LayoutInflater` (or `setContentView()`) to apply a layout resource.

Comment: can you please help me with implementing MrEngineer13's library? I cant understand how to capture "onMessageClick" for 2 separate instances of SnackBar. I really want to avoid unnecessary code that using Design Support Library entails. @CommonsWare

Comment: @magicmushroom: "I cant understand how to capture "onMessageClick" for 2 separate instances of SnackBar" -- I have not used that specific feature. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, showing your code and explaining your problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

As per the exception trace you added in the comments, I think this is caused due to the fact that you have not added dependency for `'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` in your `build.gradle` file.

Except this `CoordinatorLayout` is just used to place the floating actions which can move up/down when snack bar is shown